# Unable to start up Fedora KDE or Reinstall

Tags: linux, fedora, startup, battery

I've downloaded the recent version of fedora kde on my thinkpad laptop. It worked fine, but when I restarted and there was some sort of update for Lenovo, I've been completely shut out from fedora. It would go into the start up screen with the fedora logo then immediately shut down.

I'm unable to boot using a usb drive. The laptop also doesn't work without connection to a power adapter. I did configure the battery shutdown threshold to 30%, but I'm not sure if that affects it.

What could I possibly do to resolve this? Im not sure if I should run diagonostics or do something in grub.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.